# JINX Javascript framework extending Object causing problems with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm maintaining an existing application that uses a legacy JS framework called Jinx. I would like to place jquery on the pages of this application, problem is: the `Jinx` framework is extending the javascript type 'Object' that messes up `jquery`. The `noConflict()` function
doesn't solve this.

Here's the scenario:

1) declare jquery

2) declare jquery-ui plugin

3) declare jinx javascript framework

4) page contents and multiple javascript calls here

5) call jquery-ui function i.e: ('#calendar').datepicker();

6) javascript failure :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (object)
{
    return Object.extend.apply (this, [this, object]);
} has no method 'push'
```

---

Block of code in Jinx.js causing the problem(have no deep understanding what's going on here) :

```
Object.extend = function (destination, source)
{
    for (property in source)
    {
        destination[property] = source[property];
    }
    return destination;
}


Object.prototype.extend = function (object)
{
    return Object.extend.apply (this, [this, object]);
}
```

Can anybody think of a workaround? Badly need to get jquery running on the pages.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is not compatible with libraries that use unsafe (pre-ES5) methods to add to `Object.prototype`.  It uses `for ... in ...` loops without using a `hasOwnProperty` test, so addition of new properties (or methods) to `Object.prototype` causes unintended enumeration of those properties too.

In the code you've quoted, the `Object.extend` method is fine - it's the addition of `extend` to `Object.prototype` that's causing the problem.

If you can do without the functions that are added to the prototype, just remove them from your copy of Jinx.

Alternatively, if you know that your code is only targeting modern ES5 compatible browsers you can use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to *safely* add the method as a *non-enumerable property*:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'extend', {
    value: function() {
        return Object.extend.apply (this, [this, object]);
    }
});
```

Comment: I just decided to keep using the jinx framework on existing pages where I have to add features and for the new web pages remove jinx so that I could load jquery. I just gave up looking for a workaround.